# how to use java to implement C++ code

Tags: java, c++

That is a phone interview question.

Assume you have a C++ code, you want to implement the code by using Java rather than rewriting the code. How would you solve that?

I cannot figure out this question. Can anyone told me the solution?(is it possible by import some package or java library?)

Thanks

Comment: That's a terrible interview question.

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` to run a C++ compiler.  Well, you'd be using Java like they asked...

Comment: I am almost certain that there are libraries available to convert C++ code to Java.  I cannot imagine you should be responsible for _knowing_ those libraries rather just knowing that they likely exist (and they do, I believe).

Comment: It depends on the C++ code and the task at hand.  Java has some constructs that are more appropriate, such as interfaces.

Comment: @Jared Well, maybe, but it sure seems there would have to be an awful lot of restrictions on the C++ code.

Comment: So what did you answer?  I think the correct answer is to laugh derisively and make snorting noises.  (I said the _correct_ answer, not the answer that will get you the job.)

Comment: @ajb I've never really given much thought to converting C++ to Java.  For simple cases, it does seem fairly straightforward, but you are obviously right.  For instance in C++ you can extend several classes and you cannot in Java.  This would be difficult, I would think, to handle automatically.

Comment: can you use JNI to call the C++ code? I agree with @Mystical, this is a stupid question. I don't really even know what it means.

Comment: i also think JNI is the solution.

Comment: `implement the code by using Java` - what does that even *mean?* I mean, it can be interpreted in a *heckuva lot* different manners.

Comment: The question is meaningless. The code is already implemented, and you can't rewrite it, so the answer space is empty. Like many puzzling interview questions, the only possible answer is 'please clarify'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java Native Interface (JNI), you can use a method written in c++(or some other language) in your java code

1. Begin by writing the Java program. Create a Java class that declares the native method; this class contains the declaration or signature for the native method. It also includes a main method which calls the native method.
2. Compile the Java class that declares the native method and the main method.
3. Generate a header file for the native method using javah with the native interface flag -jni. Once you've generated the header file you have the formal signature for your native method.
4. Write the implementation of the native method in the programming language of your choice, such as C or C++. (this is what you are already given in this case).
5. Compile the header and implementation files into a shared library file.
6. Run the Java program.